# Usando mapas dinâmicos com a API do Google Maps

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

Vejo os exemplos de como usar a API do Google Maps e geralmente nos exemplos em que vejo, sempre existe uma coordenada padrão(inicial).

Agora, digamos que eu venha a fazer um programa e distribuo esse aplicativo para vários clientes no Brasil, por exemplo.

Há uma forma de eu não fixar uma coordenada, mas que o programa sempre em for abrir o mapa, tenha sempre como start(default) as coordenadas do cliente?

Assim: Se você está em João Pessoa, num determinado bairro, ele começa por essa coordenada. Sei que isso é possível, pois há muitos aplicativos que faz isso. Como eu faria isso? Uso MVC5(VS 2013), C#.

Comment: acredito que você necessite apenas de HTML Geolocation para obter as coordenadas do navegador do cliente, e setar essas para o centro do mapa, esse [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) mostra como usar, não é muito preciso, mas ja ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Não entendo bem como você vai usar o *GoogleMaps API* com C#, provavelmente vai ser um `webView`, não vou entrar em detalhes porque o `webView` pode ser algo Desktop ou WindowsPhone (ou outro tipo de dispositivo), pela tag asp-net-mvc suponho que seja web, talvez depois eu edite isso.

Se for mesmo web o asp.net-mvc é apenas a parte "back-end", no caso vou por um exemplo então apenas javascript para usar o Google-Maps a partir da posição inicial do usuário, veja um exemplo na própria documentação:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Você vai ter que usar `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` para obter a posição do usuário.

> Notas:
>
> - Troque o `YOUR_API_KEY` pela sua chave (requer uma conta do google)
> - O navegador solicita uma permissão do usuário para permitir o rastreamento

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 1
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não consegui abrir no browser e vi que há uma coordenada chumbada. A idéia é a página pegar as coordenadas local do usuário. O projeto é web e terá partes mobile, mas ainda não defini.

Answer (score 0):

No exemplo que o @Guilherme Nascimento passou eu só trocaria a função initMap()

```
function initMap() {

  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {

     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);

        var mapOptions = {
             center: myLatlng,
             zoom: 16,                        
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                        mapOptions);

     }
   }
 }
```

Desta forma só vai pegar a posição do usuario, porém se o usuário não permitir que use a localização dele você não terá mapa, ai vai ter que dar alguma mensagem para o usuário ou setar uma localização padrão.